# Extrusion problems

Tags: modeling, extrude

I have some problems with extrusions breaking up my loops.

I used the extrusion to make a new part of a mesh. I want to loop-select faces of this new extruded part, but the loop-select fails due to one edge not being selected in the loop somehow. I had this problem several times and it can range from one to more edges missing from the loop. The only way I have found to solve it was to go back before the extrusion and re-select the faces I wish to extrude. That takes too much time if I don't catch it early enough.

I worked with UV sphere mesh, trying to reproduce the flask from tutorial videos: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51SdWI-yof4

I have added the picture.

Thank you for any tips and answers.

[image: Broken loop]

Comment: It seems you extruded the face below the red circle, then canceled it and there are four face with zero are around it. Try to remove the doubles. Select everything then press alt+c and select "by distance".

Comment: The shortcut is ALT + M by default

Comment: The only thing that I extruded there were the upper faces. Then I selected the face loop that is seen on the picture, but it failed to select all the edges as well. If I were to extrude it now, I would be missing the edge on that face (I would have a "pocket" made there).

Comment: Try undoing the extrusion, then keeping the faces selected.